# Using limitTo in directive with ng-repeat removes all my items from the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-limitto

I'm building an angularJS app. I've many data to retrieve from an array of json objects, and I've to limit the number of those data, and I want to use limitTo to perform that.

I use ng-repeat inside a directive like below :

```
<my-directive
    ng-repeat="unConteneur in conteneurs | limitTo: 10"
    ng-show="(unConteneur.libelle_rubrique==rubriqueCourante || unConteneur.nom==rubriqueCourante) && hideSearch"
    contenu="unConteneur">
</my-directive>
```

But putting limitTo, removes all my items from the DOM. My code work properly when I remove limitTo. And I don't know why!

I imported angular and all other libraries correctly.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: can you see the directive in the console? Are you sure it is because of limitTo, or maybe limitTo is causing the boolean value for ng-show to be false, and it doesn't appear at all.

Comment: what does "contenu" represent in your code?

Comment: Something like this in a directive :  `.directive("contenusRubrique", function () {

    return {
     
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: '/contenusRubrique',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            contenu: "=",
            recherche: "="
        }

    }
})`

Comment: Can you create a plunker? That would help us understand better.

Comment: Nope sorry because I use an html template called Twig and plunker doesnt support that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134146/discussion-between-ayush-bahuguna-and-kabrice).